# How to design topic selection view in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Im looking for idea on how to implement topic selection view like this [image: Topic Selection]

Since the text are dynamic, my first thought is to create using a collection view with different (dynamic adoptingcell sizes)

Any other ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use CompositionalLayout to be able to set the size dynamically or you can use TagListView Pod

Search for it and you can find multiple articles about it